# Building a basic program that has user input a number to indicate instructions for a menu of options. Stuck on verifying it's an acceptable answer?

Tags: python

```
##Creation of a menu for user to choose from
print ("Please choose an activity from the list: ")
print ("1: Instruction List 1")

print "" ##Formatting line
userInput = input("Please enter your choice: ")


"""Create the desired instructions based on the user input by
integrating a function"""

def instructions_List(userInput):
    if isinstance(userInput, int) == True and userInput == 1:
       print "User instructions here"
       return
    elif userInput.isalpha():
       print "That was not an option on the menu!"
       return
    else:
       print "That was not an option on the menu!"
       return


##Run the function to do what is intended for the program

instructions_List(userInput)
```

So the idea is a user will be shown a menu of options to choose from. Once they select an option the screen will display instructions to follow for the menu options. I'm practicing my skills by first making sure the user can't input something beyond what the menu has displayed. I understand I will need to eventually integrate loops to make it restart from the beginning. But for now I'm trying to make sure it only accepts integers or floats, just anything that is not a string or not an option on the menu. When I run the code and input a string such as abc, it's kicking out errors trying to claim the string a variable in the code. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should add the language tag for better results.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code and it works just fine. [image]